# An extension that is normal but not separable

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking for an example of an normal extension but not separable; all I know is that $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ is not separable since $X^p-t$ is not. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall (or convince yourself) that every extension of degree $2$ is normal and use the example you recalled with a suitable choice of $p$.

Comment: yes, I found it ! for $K=\mathbb{F}_2(\sqrt{t})$ which is a quadratic extension over $\mathbb{F}_2(t)$ so it's normal as you said (I still have to check it out), the polynomial I gave above is not separable. thanks

Comment: Why is $X^2-t$ not separable? It has only simple roots ($\sqrt{t}$ and $- \sqrt{t}$)...

Comment: @AguirreK It is in characteristic $2$ the "roots" you give are actually *one* root (with multiplicity two).

Comment: You are right, @quid, thank you